# Inconsistent format detection by ld

Tags: assembly, rust, linker-errors, ld, bootloader

I’m writing a custom bootloader (like a lot of people on the internet seem to be actually doing :D) for the sake of it without any library.

Here is my target setup:

- The first sector is written in asm (Nasm i386 in 16 bits mode), called bootloader in the code. It will load the next sectors using the BIOS and jump to a label called `bootram_entry`.
- An arbitrary amount of sectors (hard coded to one right now) is made of Rust code (custom target, using LLVM target i386-unknown-none-code16) and will be in charge of setting up base services and load the kernel. It is called bootram, in reference to the initramfs from the Linux project.
- Those two objects are compiled using their respective tools, as you can see in the Makefile (GitHub link at the bottom of the post). They target the `elf32-i386` format, as it seems to be what one should use when a x86_64 CPU is in 16 bits real mode, from what I could gather (please tell me if I’m wrong). As shown by `objdump -f *.o`, they do indeed have this format.
- Those two objects are then linked together using a linker script (`boot.ld`), using a MEMORY section to ensure that the 0x7c00 offset is respected and to give the bootloader a reference to `bootram_entry`. It is linked to the same format (`elf32-i386`) and then copied to a binary file using `objcopy` so I can have some debugging symbols for `gdb`.

Here is the catch though: when running `make build`, both the bootloader and bootram compile correctly to the right format, but `ld` rejects them by saying that they use the wrong architecture, despite `objdump` saying that they do not.
You can find a screenshot of what I’m mentioning right here:

[image: output screenshot]

The source code can be found on this temporary repo: https://github.com/Akarys42/bootloader/tree/wip

If you wish to try to run it, you’ll obviously need binutils, nasm, rust and cargo (nightly) and the `cargo-src` component (`rustup component add rust-src`)

Any help would be really appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Googling suggests that you should use `-m elf_i386` rather than `--oformat elf32-i386`. Have you tried that?

Comment: @Michael I have no idea how I didn’t find this ; I looked over and over accros the internet without finding this solution. It seems like it did the job, thanks a lot! 

It seems like I’m still having some issues with my program counter getting misaligned, but I guess that should be the subject of another question.